# Trouble building wxwidget

Tags: cmake, mingw, wxwidgets

I've been trying to build wxwidget 3.1.5 on Windows 10 using CMake.

I simply used the command recommended on the official website:

```sh
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..\wxWidgets-3.1.5\ -DwxBUILD_TESTS=ALL
cmake --build .
```

It went smoothly until a message popped up

```
[100%] Building CXX object tests/headers/CMakeFiles/test_headers.dir/__/__/__/__/tests/allheaders.cpp.obj
In file included from D:/tools/wxwidget/wxWidgets-3.1.5/include/wx/platform.h:343,
                 from D:/tools/wxwidget/wxWidgets-3.1.5/include/wx/defs.h:45,
                 from D:/tools/wxwidget/wxWidgets-3.1.5/include/wx/wxprec.h:12,
                 from D:\tools\wxwidget\wxWidgets-3.1.5\tests\testprec.h:4,
                 from D:\tools\wxwidget\wxWidgets-3.1.5\tests\allheaders.cpp:433:
D:/tools/wxwidget/wxWidgets-3.1.5/include/wx/wxcrtbase.h:228:39: error: redundant redeclaration of 'size_t wcsnlen(const wchar_t*, size_t)' in same scope [-Werror=redundant-decls]
  228 |     wxDECL_FOR_MINGW32_ALWAYS(size_t, wcsnlen, (const wchar_t*, size_t))
```

Anybody knows how to cope with it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like a problem with wxWidgets. Have you searched their bug tracker? It doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong. https://trac.wxwidgets.org/

Comment: Which compiler are you using exactly (`g++ --version`)?

Comment: 9.2.0 @Brecht Sanders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WxWidgets already provides makefile for you. All you need to do is use it :

```
cd WxWidgets-3.1.5\build\msw
mingw32-bin.exe -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug
```

Comment: Thanks. After I find out that CMake doesn't work I use Makefile instead, but I do hope that I could use CMake ...

Comment: @Hans, why? Yuu build the library once and forget about it until its time t distribute the application? Or you have even  bigger application that is already using CMake and you want to integrate you part and let the user build it? Anyway - do you development and testing and the integration part can be done later.